# spring security, get methods and url from table and validate the authorizeRequests dinamicly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this to validate the method and resouce and role but I can not believe that this part need to set in code, exist a way to consult a table?

For example

```
table: user_access <br>
campos: url , path <br>
method="HttpMethod.GET" <br>
path="/api/clientes/page/**"
```

And I have this code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    
    //implementar reglas de seguridad para los end points
    //por el lado de oauth
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //reglas especificate al mas generico
        
**//I Dont like this part and i try to creat it dinamicly**

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/clientes","/api/clientes/page/*","/api/clientes/img/*","/images/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/clientes/form/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","SUPER_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/clientes/uploads").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","SUPER_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/clientes").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","SUPER_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/api/clientes/{id}").hasRole("SUPER_ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/clientes/{id}").hasRole("SUPER_ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().cors().configurationSource(cousConfigurationSource()); //error en el cors con esto se arregla para la pagina de angular
        
    }

    //importante no tomar cors.reactive 
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource cousConfigurationSource() {
        
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS")); //se podria poner * para todo
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type","Autorization"));
        
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source= new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
    
    //filtro //seleccionar spring Framework
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>  corsFilter(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(cousConfigurationSource()));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
```

Any Idea to make it more dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Hope below will help,

You can do it but it will work when the application starts, You can create a table to hold all of required configs, and when the application start running, you can write a code to read all of configured values and use them to configure the `HttpSecurity`.

### Example:

```java
@Entity
public class UserAccessEntity{

@Id
private String url;
private String methodName;
private List<String> userRoles;
private boolean isPattern;

// setter and getter

}


public interface UserAccessRepository extends CrudRepository<UserAccessEntity,String> {}
```

Then just do the configuration after you fetch the records from the database as below:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserAccessRepository repository;
    public ResourceServerConfig(UserAccessRepository repository){
      this.repository = repository;
    }

    // Configure this as you need.
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      repository.findAll().foreach(userAccess -> {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(userAccess.getMethodName(),userAccess.getUrl())
        .hasAnyRole(userAccess.getRoles())
      });
    }
}
```

> Only the limitation you have is that you can pre-configure all of the access before application get started, and you have to restart the server if you need to reflect any change of the user access records.

Comment: Thanks, is the solution !!! but I try to create a module that allows the administrator to control the consumption of methods and urls at runtime without needing to restart the server, is it possible?

Comment: @GabrielCortez maybe this document might help you [spring-security-architecture](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture)

Comment: @AITamimi than you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think @PreAuthorize can make your validation more dynamically: You can validate for your controller, and using spEL(Spring expression language) to combine more cases.
To enable @PreAuthorize, you need to config in the WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//enable for @PreAuthorize
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSercurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    //configs
}
```

In my example, the 'SUPER_ADMIN' or user who owned the resources can access the data from the request(get the user details information). Hope this can be helpful for you.

```
@RestController
public class UserDetailsController {
    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SUPER_ADMIN')" + "or hasAuthority('USER') and authentication.getName().equals(#username)")
    @GetMapping(path = "/user/{username}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getUserDetailByUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username, Authentication authentication) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(usersService.getUserByUsername(username));
    }
}
```

spEL references document: [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions)
, Enable @PreAuthorize reference: [Introduction to Spring Method Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security)